Add a computer to multiple Security groups using Read-Host
I am trying to add a computer to multiple Security Groups using the Read-Host to prompt for the Security group names. When doing this, I get an error:
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '"SGtest1","SGTest2","SGTest3"' under: 'DC=here,DC=here,DC=here,DC=here,DC=here'.
At line:13 char:1 Add-ADGroupMember -ID $SGs -Members $samaccount

CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("SGtest1","SGTest2","SGTest3":ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

I have tried entering the SG names at the prompt separated by commas with quotes around each SG name and without quotes. I have tried multiple entry configurations for the SGs and still get the same error.
Below is the code I am working on:
$NewDC = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the DC name you want to add - Example   "    DC1-DC1-c1-01   " without quotes'
$SecurityGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Security Group you want to add members to - Example " SGName " without quotes.  for more than one group seperate the SG name with a comma'

New-ADComputer -Name $NewDC -SamAccountName $NewDC -Path 'OU=Script Test,DC=here,DC=here,DC=here,DC=here,DC=here'
$samaccount = foreach ($NewDCs in $NewDC) {
    Get-ADComputer $NewDC -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName
}

foreach ($SecurityGroups in $SecurityGroup) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -ID $securityGroups -Members $samaccount
}

If I replace the Read-Host in the $SecurityGroup with the SG names like below, the script works flawlessly, but i really need to be able to use the Read-Host
$SecurityGroup = "SGTest1","SGTEst2","SGTest3"

Can anyone help me resolve the error so I can use the Read-Host to add a computer to multiple SGs?

Change foreach ($SecurityGroups in $SecurityGroup) { ... } to foreach ($SecurityGroups in $SecurityGroup -split ',') { ... }

The Read-Host cmdlet treats all interactive input as one (1) big string.
To turn a string with value SGTest1,SGTest2,SGTest3 into three separate strings, you can use the -split operator:
$SecurityGroups = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Security Group you want to add members to - Example " SGName " without quotes.  for more than one group seperate the SG name with a comma'

# ...

foreach ($SecurityGroup in $SecurityGroups -split ',' |ForEach-Object Trim) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -ID $securityGroups -Members $samaccount
}

Invoking Trim on each resulting substring will ensure it still works if the user inputs SGTest1, SGTest2 too
